# LAN server lag inconsistent

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I was playing on a Minecraft LAN server, hosted by me, with one friend. It was modded, so we couldn't play without lag unless we had very good computers, which we didn't.

My question is how I could have huge lag spikes on the host computer with the joined computer remaining as it was (until it was disconnected from my lagged server).

The host computer is a Mac, the other is a Windows 10.
Both have 3072MB of RAM allocated to Minecraft and are running the Java edition.
The mods used by both clients are specified in the [Farming Valley modpack](https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/farming-valley?gameCategorySlug=modpacks&projectID=254202)

Comment: Are you attempting to host a server and run a client on the same computer?  If so, you may not have enough RAM to satisfy everything.  Modified versions of Minecraft can increase the required RAM.

Comment: No, it's two separate computers.

Comment: Java Edition on Windows?

Comment: Host: Mac, Join: Windows. Both 8GB RAM and Java edition

Comment: How much of the RAM have you allocated to Minecraft on the host?  When you say LAN server, do you mean you are running a separate server file or that you opened a single player world to LAN?

Comment: 3072 MB has been allocated and I opened singleplayer to LAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you "host" a server, you are running a server and client on the same computer.  The server is a little less processing intensive, so it is able to continue running while your client lags.

I also suspect your computer may not have a dedicated GPU, or Minecraft isn't setup to use it.  The CPU is doing all the graphical processing, client processing, and server processing.  Since server processing is simpler, it can host with no problems, but your client will lag.